# This javascript function is not defined? How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´ve got this code inside a php file. It should show and hide a piece of html stuff according to specific parameters (I have a set of checkboxes and if you check them, some stuff appears or hides according to wich checkbox it is).

Now, after getting many errors because of my stylesheet, and after stripping it off, I still get this one:  "hide is not defined" in firefox error console (I´ve tried the error console in firebug, and shows nothing).

This is the code, and I don´t understand how hide could be not defined:

```
   $script =
  $("input[id^=\'edit-field-tipos-unidades-disponible-value\']").change(function(){' .
    $(".fila-matriz-gastos").hide();' .
    $(".fila-matriz-gastos").prev("label").hide();' .
    $("input[id^=\'edit-field-tipos-unidades-disponible-value\'][checked]").each(function(){' .
      var tipo = $(this).val();' .
      $(".tipo-uf-" + tipo).show();' .
      $(".tipo-uf-" + tipo).prev().show();' .
      $("input.tipo-uf-"+tipo+"[value=-1]").click(function(){' .
        $("input.tipo-uf-" + tipo).attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));' .
      });' .
    });' .
  }).change();';
```

I´m pretty much at a loss here, because I want to theme the output, but I don´t understand much of how javascript works.

Thanks!!

UPDATE:

This is the output that hides or shows:

```
    <fieldset class=" collapsible">
<legend>
<a href="#">Matriz de Gastos</a>
</legend>
<div>
<div class="form-item">
<label style="display: none;">
Gastos por
<em>Departamento</em>
:
</label>
<div class="form-checkboxes tipo-uf-131 fila-matriz-gastos hidden" style="display: none;">
<div id="edit-matriz-gastos-131--1-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label class="option" for="edit-matriz-gastos-131--1">
<input id="edit-matriz-gastos-131--1" class="form-checkbox tipo-uf-131 fila-matriz-gastos hidden" type="checkbox" value="-1" name="matriz_gastos[131][-1]" style="display: none;">
Seleccionar/deseleccionar todos
</label>
</div>
<div id="edit-matriz-gastos-131-108-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label class="checkbox" for="edit-matriz-gastos-131-108">
<input id="edit-matriz-gastos-131-108" class="form-checkbox tipo-uf-131 fila-matriz-gastos hidden" type="checkbox" value="108" name="matriz_gastos[131][108]">
Gas
</label>
</div>
```

And this is is a checkbox that hides or shows the stuff, according to click on it or not:

Checked:

```
<label style="display: block;"><label style="display: block;">
Gastos por
<em>Departamento</em>
:
</label>
<div class="form-checkboxes tipo-uf-131 fila-matriz-gastos hidden" style="display: block;">
```

Unchecked:

```
<label style="display: none;">
Gastos por
<em>Departamento</em>
:
</label>
<div class="form-checkboxes tipo-uf-131 fila-matriz-gastos hidden" style="display: none;">
```

AND ANOTHER UPDATE:

Here´s what I´ve found at [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Hide):

> Hide .hide() function - DOM manipulation
>
> This function hide the matching elements on the page. What it does is
>   to set the display configuration to 'none'. You can set a speed for
>   the disappearance 'fast', 'normal' or 'slow' and a callback function
>   being executed after the affect is allowed.
>
> Example
>
> `$("#class_div").hide();`
>
> Before
>       `<div id='class_div'>Hello world</div>   <div id='class_div_2'>Hello world</div>`
>
> After:
>       `<div id='class_div' style="display:none;">Hello world</div>   <div id='class_div_2'>Hello world</div>`

Comment: Ack! My eyes - please, for your own sanity - use a [templating engine](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/19-promising-php-template-engines/), or at least some [heredoc](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3)!

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML/JS code...

Comment: I´m so sorry about that! What should I do to make the code more readable? I´m not used to code, and didn´t know about heredoc nor how to use template angines. This is a piece of code that´s not mine, and I just wanted to understand it.

Comment: I´ve edited the information of the question... THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.hide` is probably a jQuery function. I think you removed jQuery from the page. In FireBug, got to the scripts tab and look for jQuery in the loaded files. Do you see it?

Comment: You are properly correct, but $ seems to be defined. It's properly an other framework running as well...

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is called: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> and it is there. This is a Drupal installation, and this code used to work until I changed the css...

Comment: Ok, I´m acceping the answer as a best one, but the problem didn´t got resolved... :´(

Answer (score 1):

include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in the head of your page, as Jeff already has pointed out. If you have jQuery loaded and still have that problem then you will ALSO be loading prototype.js/mootools/dojo or your tinkering with the $ function. To use jQuery next to other libraries, call ´jQuery.noConflict()´ directly after your include and replace all ´$´ with ´jQuery´ in your script.

Comment: Thanks! But, I´m not using mootools. This theme is based in Twitter´s Bootstrap, that also uses jQuery...

Comment: Could this code be in conflict with other javascript inside the file?

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is loaded in noconflict mode it doesn't matter if you are using mootools or any other library, you need to either replace $ with jQuery or assign $ back to jQuery within your function.

EG

```
jQuery("#class_div").hide();
```